# fread Only first 5 bytes of .PNG file

Tags: c, file-io, stdio, msvcrt, fread

I've made a simple resource packer for packing the resources for my game into one file. Everything was going fine until I began writing the unpacker.
I noticed the .txt file - 26 bytes - that I had packed, came out of the resource file fine, without anyway issues, all data preserved.
However when reading the .PNG file I had packed in the resource file, the first 5 bytes were intact while the rest was completely nullified.

I traced this down to the packing process, and I noticed that fread is only reading the first 5 bytes of the .PNG file and I can't for the life of me figure out why. It even triggers 'EOF' indicating that the file is only 5 bytes long, when in fact it is a 787 byte PNG of a small polygon, 100px by 100px.

I even tested this problem by making a separate application to simply read this PNG file into a buffer, I get the same results and only 5-bytes are read.

Here is the code of that small separate application:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    FILE* f = fopen("test.png", "r");
    fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), f);
    fclose(f);        //<- I use a breakpoint here to verify the buffer contents
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please point out my stupid mistake?

Comment: Why not use C++ streams?

Comment: Why is there a zero in between the brackets for "buffer"?

Comment: @Billy: To nullify the buffer, I know it's not a standard way.

Comment: @Sam: It's standard -- you just don't need the zero. `{}` is perfectly fine and does the same thing.

Comment: @GMan: Probably because the question is tagged "C"

Comment: @Ed: Do look at time stamps and edits. It was tagged C++ when my comment (and @Billy's) was made.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Can somebody please point out my stupid mistake?

Windows platform, I guess?

Use this:

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.png", "rb");
```

instead of this:

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.png", "r");
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(VS.80).aspx) for explanation.

Comment: Note that the "rb" is in the C standard and portable. It mirrors "rt" which asks for "text" treatment of the stream, which is the default. Text treatment on any *nix is the same as binary treatment. On Windows and a few other more obscure platforms they differ. In short, if you are dealing with binary data, always specify "rb" to `fopen()`.

Answer (score 8):

Extending the [correct answer from SigTerm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543069/fread-only-first-5-bytes-of-png-file/3543073#3543073), here is some background of *why* you got the effect you did for opening a PNG file in text mode:

The PNG format explains its [8-byte file header](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature) as follows:

> The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following values:

```
   (decimal)              137  80  78  71  13  10  26  10
   (hexadecimal)           89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a
   (ASCII C notation)    \211   P   N   G  \r  \n \032 \n
```

> This signature both identifies the file as a PNG file and provides for immediate detection of common file-transfer problems. The first two bytes distinguish PNG files on systems that expect the first two bytes to identify the file type uniquely. The first byte is chosen as a non-ASCII value to reduce the probability that a text file may be misrecognized as a PNG file; also, it catches bad file transfers that clear bit 7. Bytes two through four name the format. The CR-LF sequence catches bad file transfers that alter newline sequences. The control-Z character stops file display under MS-DOS. The final line feed checks for the inverse of the CR-LF translation problem.

I believe that in text mode, the call to `fread()` was terminated when it read the sixth byte which contains a Ctrl+Z character. Ctrl+Z was historically used in MSDOS (and in CPM before it) to indicate the end of a file, which was necessary because the file system stored the size of a file as a count of blocks, not a count of bytes.

By reading the file in text mode instead of binary mode, you triggered the protection against accidentally using the `TYPE` command to display a PNG file.

One thing you could do that would have helped diagnose this error is to use `fread()` slightly differently. You didn't test the return value from `fread()`. You should. Further, you should call it like this:

```
...
size_t nread;
...
nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f);
```

so that `nread` is a count of the bytes actually written to the buffer. For the PNG file in text mode, it would have told you on the first read that it only read 5 bytes. Since the file cannot be that small, you would have had a clue that something else was going on. The remaining bytes of the buffer were never modified by `fread()`, which would have been seen if you initialized the buffer to some other fill value.